# how to get the search box value in angular datatable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, angular-datatables

I'm using [angular datatable plugin](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome), and I want to get the value of the search box that comes with the generated datatable. Angular datatable has a few [options](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/api) to make a datatable, but any of them allow me specify attributes or something that I could watch with the purpose to get a particular value.

Since I need to get the value of the input search of the datatable, I can't find a way to accomplish my purpose.

**So, how can I get the search box value in angular datatable?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunetaly you cannot `$watch` the search term / filter. Angular dataTables is directives that makes jQuery dataTables *runnable* in angular without DOM conflicts etc, but the internals still works as always - in a completely none-angular way :)

However, dataTables broadcasts a `search`(`.dt`) event each time a search / filter is performed, and then you can extract the value of the search directly from the DOM :

```js
angular.element('body').on('search.dt', function() {  
   var searchTerm = document.querySelector('.dataTables_filter input').value;
   console.log('dataTables search : ' + searchTerm); 
})
```

This is of course the most simple jQuery-like approach. You may have more than one dataTable on the page and want to extract more detailed information for each search, you then can use in your angular app :

```js
angular.element('body').on('search.dt', function(e, api) {  
   if (!$scope.$$phase) { 
      $scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.searchTerm = api.oPreviousSearch;
         $scope.searchTerm.table = e.target.id;
      })   
   }  
})
```

`$apply` in order to update `$scope` from inside the event handler. `oPreviousSearch` is in fact the current search, so the above produces a `$watch`'able `searchTerm` on the form

```js
{
  "bCaseInsensitive": true,
  "sSearch": "test",
  "bRegex": false,
  "bSmart": true,
  "_hungarianMap": {
    "caseInsensitive": "bCaseInsensitive",
    "search": "sSearch",
    "regex": "bRegex",
    "smart": "bSmart"
  },
  "table": "tableId"
}
```

see demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/E5Tr7FrLRIVTtguQHFx9?p=preview**

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the actual search value with the search() function (with no arguments).

To get it updated make sure you:

Have a dtInstance and a dtOptions object:

```
<table datatable dt-instance="vm.dtInstance" dt-options="vm.dtOptions">
```

You bind a callback to "draw" event in your dtOptions:

```
this.dtOptions = { drawCallback: this.myCallbackFunction }
```

Then in your function you can do:

```
this.myCallbackFunction = () => {
   let mySearchValue = this.dtInstance.DataTable.search() 
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't require jquery